# Seiyria Slider Disable only one slider of range sliders

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a range slider and I am trying to figure out how to disable only one of the handles of sliders when ever the user picks one of the drop down options. 
I used the api code (.disable()) and it disabled all my sliders and not just one. So far I have been experimenting but with not avail.

API link: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <select class="form-control"onchange="slider1_1()" id="box1_1">
    <option value="0">Select </option>
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3 </option>
    <option value="4">4 </option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8 </option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

     </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 topmargin">
```

Jscript

```
<script>


var sliderC = new Slider("#ex12c", { id: "slider12c", min: 0, max: 10, range: true, value: [0, 0] });




function slider1_1(){

var box=document.getElementById("box1_1");
var selectedValue = box.options[box.selectedIndex].value;
var score=document.getElementById("score1_1");
score.innerHTML=selectedValue;
value_1=parseFloat(selectedValue,10);

sliderC.setValue([value_1,value_1]);
sliderC.disable(1)
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing in the API that lets you disable a singular slider in a range slider.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Also, is there a way to get the value of one of the sliders and create events in the DOM if one of the slider value changed?

Comment: Use the slide or change events.

Comment: I meant to say can the slidervalue function get the value of one of the sliders? I am trying to implement the " .on("slide", function(sliderValue) " just    for one of the handles of the sliders.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just call slider.value() or whatever it is. it'll give you an array in the case of a range slider.